# Creating "View" to connect two Databases

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have two Databases, one which looks at Financial Year 2018- 2019 and another which will be looking at Financial year 2019-2020.

Now these are Sage Databases so they have a lot of Tables within each of them, the setup of each Database is exactly the same.

Now I had a report which looked at the current financial year no problem, but I didn't realise that they had it set up as the previous financial year would be stored in a separate Database.

I've said "View" within my title, but that's not really what I need as I need whole tables.

So my question is this, is there a construct within SQL that will allow me to create a new datasource of some kind which contains the 12 tables I actually need to populate my report and the data inside these tables be a union of the 12 tables from 18-19 and the 12 tables of 19-20.

I hope that make a least a little sense.

(I would just try and make use of a view, but there's multiple datasets within the report which make use of the joins in slightly different ways)

Comment: Perhaps something like creating a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine) to the second database, then use it in the query?

Comment: Partitioned View is the way to go. You will need a linked server (per @LukStorms). See https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-partitioned-views/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#partitioned-views

Comment: Would this still work with both DB's being located on the same server? Just I see it says the Database must be the network name of the server

Comment: You don't need a linked server if on the same server

Comment: If the databases are on the same server, just create 12 `UNION ALL` views with 3-part names that reference the tables in the other database.

Comment: So if they're on the same server I can just make use of the Partioned View without the need for a linked server?

Comment: I think I haven't explained what I need very well, I need the UNIONED tables which creating those 12 views would get me no problem, but I need to be able to use those 12 views as a collective as a datasource. 

So instead of Database=OldDatabase I could have Database=12_UNION_VIEWS.

Comment: Instead of `select * from table`, you will `select * from database1..table union all select * from database2..table`.  or `database1.dbo.table` -- basically you put the database name as part of the table name.

Comment: Also -- when you say it's the same server -- is it the same SQL server instance on that server?

Comment: The contents of each table are different, they're just consistent across the two DB's so a union all wouldn't work would it? And yeah it's the same instance. 

I've just been looking at Database Snapshots, could I create a snapshot from the data stored within the views and then use that as my data source?

Comment: I am a little confused by what you mean, please proof read your comments to avoid ambiguity. What do you mean by "contents of each table are different, they're just consistent across the two DB's"? What do you mean by "Database Snapshots" and how they relate to "snapshot from the data stored within the views"?

Comment: Now would be a good time to have a rather involved discussion with your coworkers to discuss your goal and what you can, can not, and should not do. You have a licensed product which generally limits what you can legally do within the database. Your sage support people will likely have opinions (and perhaps authority). Same for the DBAs.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I was a little bit confused by the views, but I've figured out if I create the views on the old db within the reporting software I can just point it at [dbo].[view] instead of [dbo].[table] 

As for our SLA with our Sage support we have authority to create views so this should be fine.